# A recommendation for books on Lie algebra representation

Tags: book-recommendation

I am looking for a holistic book on lie algebra representation, including the infinite dimensional cases. I heard Humphrey book is standard but it does not seem to include the infinite dimensional Lie algebras

Could anyone please recommend me a book that would fit my interests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony W. Knapp has a book, namely [Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups](https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/481529), which includes infinite-dimensional representations of Lie algebras and Lie groups. There are many other books, e.g., [Unitary Representations of Reductive Lie Groups](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/4161.html) by D. Vogan. Which one fits your interests most is of course up to you.

Answer (score 1):

VS Varadarajan's [Lie Groups,  Lie Algebras, and their Representations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lie_Groups_Lie_Algebras_and_Their_Repres.html?id=uwfpBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button)  may suit your purposes.